# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx$ by changing the coordinates to r,$\theta$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

where, $x=r\cos^2\theta , y=r\sin\theta \cos\theta$

I drew the region on the [$xy$-plane over which the integral is performed](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nedmeumz0c)

After the transformation to the [$R\Theta$-plane](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qztybgfy0h)
the region changes.

To me it seems the transformed region in the $R\Theta$-plane is unbounded! But I am not sure
weather or not I am correct.

Please help me find the transformed region on the $R\Theta$-plane and the Transformed integral itself! So, I could calculate.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4754973/show-that-integral-int-02a-int-sqrt2ax-x2-sqrt4ax-x2-left1?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be split into two, each of which being solved using coordinates change differently.

Split the integral as
$$
\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx
{=
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx}_{I_1}
\\-\underbrace{\int_{0}^{2a}\int_0^{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx}_{I_2}.
}
$$
For $I_1$, through a change of variables $x\to 2a+x$ we can write
$$
I_1
{=\int_{-2a}^{0}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4a^2-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{(x+2a)^2})\ dy\ dx
\\=
\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2a}\left[1+\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{(r\cos \theta+2a)^2}\right]rdrd\theta.
}
$$
Similarly, for $I_2$, through a change of variables $x\to a+x$ we have
$$
I_2{=
\int_{-a}^{a}\int_0^{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{(a+x)^2})\ dy\ dx
\\=
\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_0^{a}\left[1+\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{(a+r\cos \theta)^2}\right]rdrd\theta.
}
$$
The rest of calculations should follow simply, however, I did not go through the details from here on. Good luck!