# Show that integral $\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\ dy\ dx=\left(\pi+\frac{8}{3}\right)a^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Show that the integral $$\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\ dy\ dx=\left(\pi+\frac{8}{3}\right)a^2$$ by changing the coordinates $x,y$ to $r$,$\theta$ where, $x=r\cos^2\theta , y=r\sin\theta \cos\theta$.

**Solution:**

$\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx
{=
{\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx}
-{\int_{0}^{2a}\int_0^{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx}
}=I_1+I_2.$

The Jacobian is $J=r cos^2(\theta)$ for the transformation $x=r\cos^2\theta , y=r\sin\theta \cos\theta$.

Hints is given in the link [Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{2a}\int_{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4ax-x^2}}(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2})\ dy\ dx$ by changing the coordinates to r,$\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4740441/evaluate-the-integral-int-02a-int-sqrt2ax-x2-sqrt4ax-x21-fr)

Q1: Please help me to solve the problem. How to transform $I_1,I_2$ using the given transformation $x=r\cos^2\theta, y=r\sin\theta \cos\theta$. I evaluate concern Jacobian, but unable to understand the limits in $r-\theta$ plane.

Q2: I understand the Fig in x-y plane which is the common portion of two circles in the 1st quadrant which are $(x-a)^2+y^2=a^2$ (inner) and $(x-2a)^2+y^2=(2a)^2$. But I cannot understand the Fig in $r-\theta$ plane. Please explain the transformation $x=rcos^2θ,\,y=rsinθ\,cosθ$.

Comment: The transformations $x\rightarrow x+2a$ and $x\rightarrow x+a$ in the link attached shift the centres of the semicircular regions of integration to coincide with the origin. Ordinary polar coordinates are then applied to solve the integrals $I_1$ and $I_2$.

Comment: @CW279 How under such transformation, the given transformation $x=r\cos^2\theta , y=r\sin\theta \cos\theta$ chages to $x=rcosθ,y=rsinθ$. Would you please write in a answer style in details. Where is the problem if one use the transformation directly?

Comment: What is the need of the given transformation $x=r\cos^2\theta , y=r\sin\theta \cos\theta$

Comment: Please ask **one question**. Please define all objects, for instance what are that **I_1, I2** - are they possibly some $I_1$ and $I_2$ from a linked answer? What does it mean "you took", i did not take anything. And i really do not want to go to the linked answer in order to understand the present question. Please write everything self-contained. The Jacobian $J$ is the Jacobian for which transformation? What means to "handle such transformation"? If this means to apply the 2D-substitution, please show your own effort. Q2 is unclear. Which Fig.? The answer should focus on what?

Comment: And for Q3: What is not clear? The function $(r,t)\to(r\cos^t, r\sin t\cos t)$ is clear enough. And finally, please use normal, not bold face font. It feels like the difference between speak and shout.

Comment: @dan_fulea I have edited. Hope this version may be clear. If not, please comment...I will try again to clear it.

Comment: @dan_fulea Also, please comment on $(r,t)\to(r\cos^2 t, r\sin t\cos t)$, as you mentioned it is clear enough.

Comment: OK, now it is everything fine, we have a good nice question, i will try to give an answer to the point!

Comment: @dan_fulea All is possible due to your earlier comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The substitution from $(x,y)$ to the "modified" polar coordinates via $(x,y)=r\cos t\; (\cos t,\sin t)$ is indeed a good idea, and good to remember. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following pictures explains the idea of the "non-standard" substitution.

[image: mse question 4754973 modified polar coordinates]

We have two disks in the picture. The one in dark red
with diameter between the origin and $(2a,0)$, and
the one in light red
with diameter between the origin and $(4a,0)$.
Consider now a radar line moving around the origin.
Fix its position to build the angle $t$ with the $Ox$-axis.
It hits the two circles, the boundaries of the disks in (the origin and)
the two points $A,B$. By homotethy, $2OA=OB$. Which is the distance between $O$ and $A$? It is the one leg of the right triangle with right angle in $A$ and opposite side the diameter of the first disk, of length $2a$. So
$$
\begin{aligned}
OA &= 2a\cos t\ ,\\
OB &= 4a\cos t\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Which are the affixes / complex images of the points $A,B$. We denote these complex numbers also by $A,B$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= 2a\cos t\cdot e^{it}=2a\cos t\cdot (\cos t+i\sin t)\ ,\\
B &= 4a\cos t\cdot e^{it}=4a\cos t\cdot (\cos t+i\sin t)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So it is natural to consider the substitution for a point $(x,y)$ running in the disk difference (light red, not dark red, only) $\Delta$:
$$
(x,y)=r\cos t(\cos t, \sin t)\ .
$$
Which is exactly the suggested substitution. From the picture, the domain $\Delta$ for $(x,y)$ corresponds to $(r,t)\in[2a,4a]\times [-\pi/2,\; \pi/2]$. We obtain for instance as an warming up exercise:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_\Delta\left(1 +\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\;dx\; dy
&=
\int_{2a}^{4a}dr
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
\left(1 +\frac{\sin^2 t}{\cos^2 t}\right)\;r\cos^2 t\; dt
\\
&=
\left(
\int_{2a}^{4a}r\;dr
\right)
\left(
\int_{-\pi/2}^{+\pi/2}
(\cos^2 t+\sin ^2 t)
\;dt
\right)=6\pi a^2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
However, the given integral $J$ is not an integral on the full $\Delta$. Fubini gives for the posted integral the constraints $x\in[0,2a]$, and $y\ge 0$, chosen so that $y^2$ is between $2ax-x^2$ and $4ax-x^2$. This means $x\in[0,2a]$, and
$x^2 -2ax+a^2+y^2\ge a^2$, and $x^2 -4ax+4a^2+y^2\le (2a)^2$.
So the given integral is an integral on the intersection $x\le 2a$, $y\ge 0$ with $\Delta$. We have two cases.

- For an angle $t$ with $|t|\le \pi/4$ we obtain a point $C$ as in the picture. The distance $OC$ depends on $t$, it is $2a/\cos t$.
  So $r$ varies between $2a$ and $2a/\cos ^2t$, so that $r\cos t$ varies between $OA$ and $OC$.
- For the angles $t$ with $|t|$ between $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2$ we have an $r$ varying between fixed boundaries, $2a$ and $4a$.

As we saw in the warming up,
$(1\ +\ y^2/x^2)\; dx\; dy$ gets translated into $r\; dr\; dt$.
So we can compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J
&=
\int_{\substack{(x,y)\in\Delta\\x\le 2a\\ y\ge 0}}
\left(1 +\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\;dx\; dy
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/4}
\;dt
\int_{2a}^{2a/\cos^2 t}
r\; dr
+
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
\;dt
\int_{2a}^{4a}
r\; dr
\\
&=
\int_0^{\pi/4}
2a^2\left(\frac 1{\cos^4 t}-1\right)\;dt
+
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
6a^2\;dt
\\
&=\frac 16(16-3\pi)a^2
+ \frac 14 6a^2
=a^2\left(\frac 83-\frac \pi 2+\frac{3\pi}2\right)
=
\bbox[lightblue]{\ a^2\left(\frac 83 + \pi\right)\ }
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

*Note:*
The expression $dt/\cos^4t$ was easy to integrate. Use the substitution
$u$ for the tangent of $t$. Then $1+u^2=1/\cos^2 t$, and $du$ is $dt/\cos^2t$, so we have to integrate $(1+u^2)\; du$. The denominator $3$ appears...

Comment: "Which are the affixes / complex images of the points A,B
. We denote these complex numbers also by A,B
A=2acost⋅eit,B=4acost⋅eit" ====>

I am unable to understand only this part.  How A=$2acost⋅e^{it}$,B=$4acost⋅e^{it}$, the multiplication with $e^{it}$...

Comment: You have used |t|≤π/4 meaning -π/4≤ t≤π/4, but we are concerned about 1st quadrant. So I think the limit would be 0 ≤ t≤π/4 in place of |t|≤π/4 . Is not it?

Comment: In the Fig also the centers would be (a,0) and (2a,0)

Comment: The point $A$ is a point with distance $R=2a\cos t$ from the origin, and the angle between $OA$ and the $Ox$-axis is $t$. So the point $A$, seen as a point in $\Bbb C$, is $$A=R\cdot e^{it}=R(\cos t + i\sin t)\ .$$Now replace $R$ by its specific value $R=2a\cos t$. The point $B$ is $B=2A\in\Bbb C$. This leads to the formulas for $x,y$ when identified from $$x+iy = R(\cos t+i\sin t)\ .$$Then later, yes, we need only values $t\ge 0$ for the integral. (But it doesn't hurt to keep the discussion more general, the picture with the two rays with angles $\pm\pi/4$ were already drawn.)

Answer (score 1):

I would set it up in standard polar coordinates, and I would certainly stop thinking about your $I_1$ and $I_2$. The small circle has polar equation $r=2a\cos\theta$ and the large circle has polar equation $r=4a\cos\theta$. The integral splits into two pieces (draw the picture):

(1) When $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$, the ray at angle $\theta$ from the origin enters the region at $r=2a\cos\theta$ and exits it at $r=2a\sec\theta$ (the line $x=2a$).

(2) When $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$, the ray at angle $\theta$ enters the region at $r=2a\cos\theta$ and exits it at $r=4a\cos\theta$.

Thus, your integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{2a\cos\theta}^{2a\sec\theta} \sec^2\theta\,r\,dr\,d\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{2a\cos\theta}^{4a\cos\theta}\sec^2\theta\,r\,dr\,d\theta.$$
I leave it to you to understand the details and finish.

If you use the modified polar coordinate transformation you're given (which I probably would not have thought of doing), then the new equations of the two circles become $r=2a$ and $r=4a$ instead — so this is why they suggested that transformation. (Just substitute the given equations into $x^2+y^2=2cx$.) The equation of the line $x=2a$ becomes $r=2a\sec^2\theta$.
So now the integrals become
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_{2a}^{2a\sec^2\theta} \sec^2\theta\,r\cos^2\theta\,dr\,d\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{2a}^{4a}\sec^2\theta\,r\cos^2\theta\,dr\,d\theta,$$
which is indeed conveniently simpler.

Comment: For the 2nd case, how the modified polar coordinate transformation, transforms the equation of the line $x=2a$  to $r=2asec^2θ$ ?

Comment: @user1942348 What do you not see? Divide by $\cos^2\theta$.